# How do I install Flash Player 11 debug version in 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, installation, flash

I want to replace my existing browser plugin Flash Player with the debug version, and update to FP11 while I'm at it.  I also want to install the debug version of the projector player and make it the default player for SWF files outside of the browser.

First the browser plugin version.  I've downloaded the installer from [the official site](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html), but I'm not sure what to do with the contents. There is a `usr` folder, and I presume that I am to write the contents of this to `/usr`.  There is also a file called 
`libflashplayer.so`, and I have no idea what to do with that.

For download for the projector player has confused me further because it only contains one file: `flashplayerdebugger`. I don't know what to do with this.

If there is a way to install these softwares through apt-get or the Software Center I would love to hear about it, I have only found solutions for the standard player, but otherwise could someone please tell me what to do with these files?

### Update

Ok, so I've figured out that if I dump the `flashplayerdebugger` file into /usr/lib/ I can point Eclipse at it and compile and test SWFs as expected from inside Eclipse. But how can I set that application as the default player when I select an SWF in Nautilus?

Comment: ~/.mozilla/plugins/

Comment: My `mozilla/plugins/` folder seems to be in `/usr/lib/`. I've copied libflashplayer.t it doesn't seem to have made a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to copy `libflashplayer.so` to either ~/.mozilla/plugins or /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins. If you choose the first option, the debug version will only be available for your user. The `usr` folder in the archive is just the settings manager, a program for changing preferences and settings.

Comment: I've moved that file into `/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins`, but I'm still not getting debug messages in the browser. The same SWF is throwing an error in the standalone debug player.